# ArcObjects -- How to tell if an event is already wired up

Tags: arcobjects, c#, events

Using Visual Studio 2010 C# and ArcMap 10.1.

In a custom ArcObjects extension, a bunch of events are wired up at startup.  For example, this simple standard code chunk:

```
        IEditEvents_Event m_EditEvents = (IEditEvents_Event)m_Editor;
        m_EditEvents.OnStartEditing += EditEvents_OnStartEditing;
        m_EditEvents.OnCreateFeature += EditEvents_OnCreateFeature;  
        m_EditEvents.OnChangeFeature += EditEvents_OnChangeFeature;
        m_EditEvents.OnDeleteFeature += EditEvents_OnDeleteFeature;
        m_EditEvents.OnStopEditing += EditEvents_OnStopEditing;
```

Later on in the program, depending on the state of things, any particular handler might have been turned off (-=) or turned back on (+=).  While debugging, I am interested in using some sort of Visual Studio debug/diagnostic tool or ArcObjects interface that allows me to see with some sort of detail either (or both):

- the function that is wired up to any particular object.event
- the events that are wired up to any particular method

Comment: Hi Rob, I've done some Googling on this and they only way I found was to keep a boolean for each (true at wiring, false at unwiring, initial false) to keep track of which events I'd wired and unwired. Do you think though this is a stack overflow question rather than a GIS.SE question? Even though they are Esri events they're still only events..

Comment: Michael, I had considered the boolean approach, but was hoping for something 'built-in' that didn't require hardcoding.  You are correct that this is a more Stack Overflow oriented question...

Comment: Me too Rob, after searching around for a few wasted hours I settled on the boolean approach... it works. If you do find something to discern if an event is wired please answer this question, as I would be *very* interested to see if there's a better way.